# Does Apache Oltu support open id connect implementation?

Tags: openid-connect, oltu

We are working on making our web application open id connect compliant and when i look up apache oltu library, i dont see any ways to set "idtoken" in the /token endpoint. The documentation says Apache Oltu has open id connect support but i dont see a java class for it. Is OAuthASResponse.OAuthAuthorizationResponseBuilder supposed to set the idtoken with setParams() method ?
Any pointers?

Comment: you probably meant to write "OpenID Connect compliant" rather than "open id 2.0 compliant"

Comment: yes, thank u for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it supports openid connect implementation and you can set the id_token using the setparam as below:

```
OAuthResponse oResponse = OAuthASResponse
                    .tokenResponse(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)
                    .setAccessToken("abc").setExpiresIn("3600")
                    .setParam("id_token", "a1b2").buildJSONMessage();
```